# Create a list with specific size and fill it with values in python

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list in python based on user input.
For instance if a user input 3 I want to know how to create a list which has length 3 and it should be filled with values 1,2 and 3.

Ex:

User Input = 3

List = [1, 2, 3]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Surely, you must have given this an attempt already? Can you please show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you just want to create a list of size `n` with some default value say `None`, you can do it like:

```
>>> my_size = 3
>>> [None]*my_size
[None, None, None]
```

But in case in case you are certain about the values in the `list` as you mentioned i.e `1` to `n` then you can do it using `range()` as:

```
# In Python 2.7
>>> range(1, my_size+1)
[1, 2, 3]

# In Python 3, you need to explicitly type-cast it to 'list'
>>> list(range(1, my_size+1))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

`range(1, int(raw_input()) + 1)`

Python 3:

`list(range(1, int(input()) + 1))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.